# Derive log loss Gradient Descent in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

Derive log loss Gradient Descent in Python,

Can anyone help me with basic code for gradient descent so that I can understand

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one for you

##Code:

```py
def log_loss_prime(y_true, y_pred):
    return ((1 - y_true) / (1 - y_pred) - y_true / y_pred) / np.size(y_true)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).